# Why my form submission does not work with php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to get this form submission working, but I'm not familiar with php. I have bought this but it does not seem to be working.

When I press the submit button nothing will happen! I'm just trying to find out if the code is written correctly.

Thank you in advance

HTML Code

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" action="contact.php">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="column">
     <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnlast">

      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <textarea cols="1" name="message" rows="4"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

   //Retrieve form data. 
   //GET - user submitted data using AJAX
   //POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
   $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
   $email = isset($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
   $phone = isset($_GET['phone']) ?$_GET['phone'] : $_POST['phone'];
   $message = isset($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

   if ($_POST) $post=1;

   $errors = array();

   if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
   if (!$phone) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your phone.'; 
   if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
   if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

   //If the errors array is empty, send the mail
   if (!$errors) {

   // ====== mail here  ====== //
   $to = 'Ardi Mir <ardmir87@hotmail.com>';

   // Sender
   $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

   //subject and the html message
   $subject = 'Message from your website';  
   $message = '
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head></head>
   <body>
   <table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone:</td><td>' . $phone . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>     
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td>' . nl2br($message) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

} else {
    echo $result;   
}

} else {}

function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to allow both `GET` and `POST`, you can use `$_REQUEST`. It merges `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar It's important to also note that cookies also land in `$_REQUEST`, and that the order of precedence is configurable in PHP.ini, which can make it unreliable depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Nothing happens, or you get a blank page? Enable error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",1);`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I ran error reporting gave me 3 errors all relating to the "phones". I deleted them, as did not have phone inpput. The errors are gone but it still won't send any email.

Comment: @Ardavan Consult my answer below. I've tested it and mail was sent and received. It did not send when the `phone` form field was not in there, so I added it and it worked. If mail is still not being sent, if hosted, contact your web host provider. If on a local machine, check your settings and that `mail` is indeed installed and properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your form is not working and mail not sending is because it is missing the `phone` field.

Add the following to your HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*">
```

and it will work.

If [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) were set/included in your PHP, it would have thrown the following, or similar to:

> Notice: Undefined index: phone in /path/to/your/file.php on line X

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

- This was tested on my own hosted service and not a local machine.

---

Comment: Is there a way that I could make the form disappear after submission? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Ardavan You can either do a header redirect to another page, or add an `exit;`

Comment: After the fixation, it started to give "Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later" message after pressing submit. Please help. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly put your code on my local webserver and looked into it.

First on, replace

```
if(!$errors)
```

with

```
if(empty($errors))
```

if you use `!$variable`, then PHP will check if the variable is a bool with content `FALSE`.

```
$foo=false;
if(!$foo) {...} else {...}
```

Next on, you are expecting a phone number.

```
Array ( [0] => Please enter your phone. )
```

I figured this out by putting the following at line 56 of your code:

```
} else {print_r($errors);}
```

`print_r(...)` lets you view the contents of a variable in a human readable format. Its often used for debugging.

Otherwise, I have not spotted any error. So what you have to fix, in a nutshell:

- Replace the if-statement above to correctly check for an empty array.
- Never leave an else statement blank while debugging, that could become a pitfall. Use print_r during debugging, but nto during production, as it could offer somebody some valuable information about your code/setup.

The PHP manual also has some nice things about the `empty()` function to tell: http://php.net/empty

Same for `print_r`: http://php.net/print_r